# Was bedeutet "Gut" in diesem Kontext

Tags: meaning, idiom

Die Frage bezieht sich nicht auf die erste und beliebteste Bedeutung von **gut** (a.k.a good im Englischen).

In vielen verschiedenen Kontexten habe ich die anderen Verwendungen von **gut** gehört/gelesen, aber ich konnte die Bedeutung dieses Wortes nicht richtig interpretieren.

z.B

> Ich bin **guter** Dinge

oder

> Zu **guter** Letzt

oder

> sein **gutes** Recht

Sind diese Verwendungen redensartlich und bedeuten einfach **good** wie immer oder gibt es irgendeine mystische Bedeutung von **gut**, die Nichtmuttersprachler bzw. ich nicht kennen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deine Beispiele sind unterschiedlicher Natur:

> Ich bin guter Dinge

In diesem Beispiel ist gut durchaus in dem Sinn in Verwendung, die Du kennst, als *good*.

Die beiden anderen Beispiele verwenden *gut* als verstärkendes Element.

> Zu guter letzt

Meint: Als allerletztes, ist eine deutsche Redewendung, hier lässt sich das *gut* nicht getrennt betrachten.

> sein gutes Recht

Meint: Es ist ganz bestimmt sein Recht. Wird auch idiomatisch betrachtet als Gesamtausdruck.

Es gibt weitere Beispiele mit gut:

> Wir sind schon ein gutes Stück weiter

Auch hier ist gut ein bestärkendes Element und meint ein *großes* Stück weiter.

Insgesamt kann gut eine Reihe von Bedeutungen annehmen, hier ein Auszug aus dem [deutschen Wikiwörterbuch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gut), Deine Beispiele gehören in dem Fall zum Punkt 3.

**Bedeutungen:**

1. vom Menschen her positiv bewertet, empfunden, gefühlt und dergleichen

   - prädikativ oder attributiv gebraucht
   - adverbiell gebraucht
2. eine Schulnote

   - (Deutschland und Österreich) entspricht der Note 2
   - (Schweiz) entspricht der Note 5
3. mit Zahl- oder Maßangaben: reichlich bemessen, etwas mehr als angegeben
4. jemandem freundlich gesinnt, jemandem zugetan
5. für besonders feierliche Anlässe gedacht
6. ohne größere Mühen zu erledigen, leicht machbar

Comment: Nicht ganz einig mit "guter Dinge" - Das lässt sich nicht mit "gut" übersetzen, sondern heisst "ich bin zuversichtlich/hoffnungsfroh". *I am of good things* ist im Englischen nicht besonders aussagekräftig...

Comment: ich sagte nicht, dass sich "guter Dinge" wörtlich übersetzen lässt, nur dass das "gut" in dieser Redewendung tatsächlich die Bedeutung des englischen "good" hat... Hätte ich vielleicht deutlicher unterscheiden sollen.

Answer (score 3):

All three examples are standard idioms where "gut" wouldn't necessarily translate to "good".

> Ich bin guter Dinge, dass...

Doesn't have anything to do with *good things* - Translates to *I am confident that...* or *I have high hopes that...*

The etymology is interesting, apparently, the "Dinge" part relates to an old MHD term "Gedinge" that means *confidence*.

> Zu guter Letzt

Simply translates to *eventually*, and does in no way imply what happened was actually *good* - You can very well say *Zu guter Letzt hatte ich auch noch einen Unfall*

Here the etymology is interesting as well. "Letzt" apparently relates to the archaic verb "letzen" (today still present in *verletzen*) that meant "to hurt so", but also "to end sth")

> Sein gutes Recht haben

Here *gut* is maybe the closest to *good* - Translates to something like *in all fairness he's allowed to...*

Comment: I found the etymology parts of your answer very interesting and helpful. With these *Eselsbrücke*, it is much easier to keep the words in mind.